# Urdu Words can't be written in overleaf

Tags: sharelatex, documentclass-writing, overleaf

I am writing Urdu words in the Overleaf but it does not appear in the text. May someone please help me? I have tried wits Arabic, but it does not work.

For example, in Urdu, I am writing " the coming month name is مارچ". So, overleaf only showed "the coming month name is   ". It does not show an Urdu word.

May someone guides me on how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[]{iosart2c}     
%\documentclass[wias]{iosart2c}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{times}%



%\usepackage{natbib}% for bibliography sorting/compressing
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%%%%%%%% Put your definitions here
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand*{\OK}{\ding{51}}
%%%%%%%%%%% End of definitions

\pubyear{0000}
\volume{0}
\firstpage{1}
\lastpage{1}

\begin{document}
    " the coming month name is مارچ"
\end{document}
```

This is just an example. It does show error.

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char د (U+62F) (inputenc) not set up
>   for use with LaTeX. See the inputenc package documentation for
>   explanation. Type H  for immediate help. ... the coming month
>   name is مارچ Your command was ignored. Type I   to
>   replace it with another command, or  to continue without it

This is the link of the overleaf file. 
[https://www.overleaf.com/5228311252vrbszchrmgsp][1]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue!

Comment: \begin{document}" the coming month name is مارچ" \end{document}" This is just an example. It does show any error. Package inputenc Error: Unicode char د (U+62F)

(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
the coming month name is مارچ

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

Comment: Can you please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable? In your code snippet is no package `inputenc` used, the error message shows it :-( We need the exact code to be able to reproduce your error and to play with it. BTW: I do not have urudu, in that problem I can not help you, sorry. BTW2: If you want to ping me, add a `@` before my name. Because youare the OP it is not needed for me, you are pinged automaticaly...

Comment: I suspect this is not an issue with Overleaf, but rather with the document class itself. With the `iosart2c` template available from http://www.iospress.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/JIFS-Submission-Templates-LaTeX.zip, loading `arabtex` (to be compiled with pdflatex) breaks the abstract. Loading `fontspec` (to be compiled with xelatex) fails with `Control sequence \c__fontspec_shape_it_sc_tl already defined.`

Comment: @LianTzeLim, thanks for your time, this is the link. https://www.overleaf.com/5228311252vrbszchrmgsp
may you please see what is the issue?

Comment: If possible, I would recommend switching your TeX engine to XeTeX and loading either `babel` or `polyglossia`. Then, load an Arabic font, for example, Amiri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me in Overleaf if I copy the class file from your project and set the compiler to XeLaTeX:

```
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\documentclass{iosart2c}

%\usepackage{natbib}% for bibliography sorting/compressing
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%%%%%%%% Put your definitions here
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{unicode-math} % If you need this.

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures = TeX }

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[
  Scale = 1.0 ]
\newfontfamily\urdufont{Amiri}[
  Script = Arabic ,
  Language = Urdu ]
\newfontfamily\pifont{DejaVu Sans}  

\newcommand*{\OK}{{\pifont ^^^^2714}}
%%%%%%%%%%% End of definitions

\begin{document}
``The name of the coming month is \texturdu{مارچ}. \OK"
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

This changes a number of the packages you used, in particular to use Unicode fonts and `polyglossia` rather than legacy fonts.  Your publisher might or might not let you do this.  It might or might not be compatible with their class file—likely not.  But, I personally recommend you use the new toolchain when you can and the legacy fonts when you have to.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please tell me how to set the compiler to XeLaTeX? This code still does not work in overleaf. Is it possible for you to debug the code I provided the link here?

Comment: It’s an option under the menu in the left bar.